# how to faster read text file to ArrayList on android

Tags: java, android, text, file-io, arraylist

I have a problem with fast read txt file to ArrayList. If I want read a file size 0,9MB, I must wait 5min. If files size is 34MB (partialy, because android does not accept larger than 1MB files), it's completely not working.
I think that process should be max few second.

This is a code:

```
String word; 
public ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setup() 
{

  try {
      AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
      InputStream inputf;
      inputf = assetManager.open("dict_1.txt");
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputf));

      word = " ";      
      while(word != null)
      {
        word =  reader.readLine();

        if (word != null)
          dictionary.add(word);
      }
      if(reader.equals("null")) println("No file found");

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    println("No file found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for my english. I hope that all is understadable.

Comment: Start by using Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: 'reader' cannot possibly equal "null", and a NullPointerException doesn't inherently mean 'no file found'. I suggest you fix your strange error- and exception-handling.

Comment: I fix the exception-handling, but it is not important if file is readed completely, though too slow.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ArrayList` keeps getting reallocated as you're adding items. This can consume a non-trivial amount of CPU time, especially as the list grows, since a bunch of pointers need to copied around in memory. A better approach would be to store the number of entries as the first item of the dictionary file, and then pre-allocate the `ArrayList`:

```
 dictionary = new ArrayList<String>(numberOfEntries);
```

A more advanced optimization would be a data structure that doesn't rely on a Java collection class at all. Depending on your needs, this could be a huge UTF-8 byte array that is read into memory in one swoop (or even accessed via a memory-mapped file).

Comment: "could be a huge UTF-8 byte array that is read into memory in one swoop (or even accessed via a memory-mapped file)" - how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is adding word to arraylist `In arraylist` read operations are constant time - O(1) but `write` operations have the potential to run out of space in the `backing array`, `re-allocation`, and a `copy` - so that runs in O(n) time.so you should use `linkedlist` instead of `arraylist`.It provide efficiency `o(1)`(for adding)

```
LinkedList<String> dictionary = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: +1 However, I'm assuming the OP is going to want some kind of random access to the list items. Those read operations will be very slow -- O(n) slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, both method give the same result. I change to Pre-allocate ArrayList and LinkedList, and nothin changes. Read time is still a long.